# cannot retrive Data from fetch

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Frontend snippet

```
const dateObj = { Date: date }
    const raw = JSON.stringify(dateObj)
    console.log(raw);
 const fetchData = async () => {
      const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/foodsSend', {
        method: 'PATCH',
        headers: myHeaders,
        body: raw

      })
      const datasss = await response.json()
      console.log(datasss);
    }
```

backend Snippet

```
router.patch('/foodsSend', auth, async (req, res) => {

    console.log(req.body.Date)


    try {
        await req.user.populate({
            path:'foods',
            match:{
                date:req.body.Date
            }
        }).execPopulate()
        console.log(req.user.foods)
        res.send(req.user.foods)
     
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(500).send()
    }
})
```

when i make the same request from Postman, i get the array of data back, but it is not working for fetch in browser. I also console logged the date, In both the case(via browser or postman) the date is same 04/14/2020 and of type string. still only postman returns the data not the fetch api. please help

Comment: Can you define "is not working for fetch in browser"? Does it give you an error? Does it never return? Does it return empty data? What isn't working?

Comment: it is returning an empty object while using fetch from browser

Comment: but when i use postman it returns the data

Comment: Are your headers/user the same for both?

Comment: Is req.user.foods logging the same thing from both browser and postman?